# JavaScript var visibility

Tags: javascript, function, oop, visibility

Given this code:

```
function MyClass() {
    var v = '1';
    this.hi = function() {
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v);
        var v = '2';
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v);
        delete(v);
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v);
    }
}
```

When I do something like:

```
z = new MyClass();
z.hi();
```

The result I get is:

```
Value of V is undefined 
Value of V is 2
Value of V is 2
```

What I want to explain is why the result is like this.

- Why V is undefined (The way I understand it - and it might not be right - is that in JS it's all definition-time, not run-time, so on definition the function had it's own variable "v", but it's not defined on the first line yet though).
- Why V is not deleted? Kept the same value?
- How do I access the "v" with value "1" from the "one-level-up"?
- I know if I use different variable name in the "hi" function, I'll be able to "see" variable "v" with the value "1" in the function. So I am kind of hiding the original one, but that still leaves the question #3 -- how do I access the "top level one"?

Thanks!

Comment: `delete` only works on Object Properties.

Answer (score 2):

[You can't `delete` a variable like that](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

You can't access the `v` from the enclosing scope because the `v` in the inner scope "hides" it. Rename it.

Answer (score 1):

As to the **why** undefined part, what your code compiles to is:

```
function MyClass() {
    var v = '1';
    this.hi = function() {
        var v;
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v); // undefined!
        v = '2';
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v);
        delete(v);
        console.log('Value of V is ' + v);
    }
}
```

As you can see the var is declared at the beginning of the scope. This is how JS works. Run it through JSLint and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.v = '1';
...
```

And make sure you always use this function with `New`.

`this` refers to the object that the thing is a member of. So creating `this.hi` makes something in a scope totally unrelated to the function itself, but using `this` for all members makes them all part of the same object (to which the function is assigned).

http://jsfiddle.net/hHvUq/